# XCode archving/building low cpu usage?

Tags: xcode

When building or archiving my app I noticed that my CPU usage is quite low considering what XCode is doing < 35%. Would allowing XCode to use more CPU make it build and archive faster? If so, how could I do this?

Any help would be great, thanks!